# How to group user registered by date

Tags: angular, firebase

I have a problem to group users document by registration date in Angular and Firebase

and document are like

```
email "demo1@gmail.com"
gender "male"
id "42PWIOI0OiMtyOpfu7tfK34apj92"
name "John Doe"
phone "+1765435689"
reg_date April 2, 2019 at 2:10:09 PM UTC+3


email "demo2@gmail.com"
gender "female"
id "96PWHDI0OiMtyOpfu7tfK34apj92"
name "Jane Doe"
phone "+187643489"
reg_date April 4, 2019 at 6:10:09 PM UTC+3

email "demo3@gmail.com"
gender "male"
id "55PWIUTGDiMtyOpfu7tfK34apj92"
name "Wlly Doe"
phone "+1768885689"
reg_date April 2, 2019 at 2:10:09 PM UTC+3


email "demo4@gmail.com"
gender "male"
id "96PWHDI0OiMtyOpfu7tfK34apj92"
name "Olie Doe"
phone "+187643489"
reg_date April 4, 2019 at 2:10:09 PM UTC+3
```

And the result needed is to group data by reg_date

Comment: 1) Are you talking about Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore? 2) Cloud you be more specific about what exactly you want your query to return? "group data" is very vague.

Comment: What do you mean by 'grouping'? What is the desired output?

Comment: @DougStevenson  Cloud Firestore, and i want to group data based on registration date and get their total For Example If there is two user registered on 8-5-2019, 1 user registered on 7-5-2019 then the result should be 2 user for 8-5-2019 and 1 user for 7-5-2019

Comment: Then you need to also somehow store the date *without* the time, and query only for exact date matches.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly do you need, but here is one way to group them by `reg_date`. I make use of [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and then create a new object using [Object.Assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), with the `reg_date` as the 'main' property.

```js
const data = [{
    email: "demo1@gmail.com",
    gender: "male",
    id: "42PWIOI0OiMtyOpfu7tfK34apj92",
    name: "John Doe",
    phone: "+1765435689",
    reg_date: "April 2, 2019 at 2:10:09 PM UTC+3"
  },
  {
    email: "demo2@gmail.com",
    gender: "female",
    id: "96PWHDI0OiMtyOpfu7tfK34apj92",
    name: "Jane Doe",
    phone: "+187643489",
    reg_date: "April 4, 2019 at 6:10:09 PM UTC+3"
  },
  {
    email: "demo3@gmail.com",
    gender: "male",
    id: "55PWIUTGDiMtyOpfu7tfK34apj92",
    name: "Wlly Doe",
    phone: "+1768885689",
    reg_date: "April 2, 2019 at 2:10:09 PM UTC+3"
  },
  {
    email: "demo4@gmail.com",
    gender: "male",
    id: "96PWHDI0OiMtyOpfu7tfK34apj92",
    name: "Olie Doe",
    phone: "+187643489",
    reg_date: "April 4, 2019 at 2:10:09 PM UTC+3"
  }
]

const result = data.reduce((h, obj) => Object.assign(h, {
  [obj['reg_date']]: (h[obj['reg_date']] || []).concat(obj)
}), {});

console.log(result);
```